# python map 2 lists showing all duplicates

Tags: duplicates, mapping

I have two lists:

```
data = [10, 20, 40, 40, 100, 100]
pinL = [27, 22, 10, 9, 11, 5]
```

Using `dictionary = dict(zip(data, pinL))` generates

```
{27: 10, 22: 20, 9: 40, 5: 100}
```

I tried

```
dictionary = defaultdict(list)

for delvt, pin in zip(data, pinL):
    dictionary[delvt].append(pin)
```

but this generates

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {40: [10, 9], 10: [27], 20: [22], 100: [11, 5]})
```

Desired output:

```
{27: 10, 20: 22, 40: 10, 40: 9, 100: 11, 100: 5}
```

The reason for this is I have got a picker and it selects a varied combination of keys and their corresponding values from the list at each given time. How best can I arrive at my desired output?

Comment: the desired output is wrong, dict can't have duplicate keys

Comment: how else can i do this without dict?

Comment: a list of tuples, for ex.